# Memoryleak when using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++

Im trying out unique_ptr to see how memory managment works in c++.

Ding.h

```
#pragma once
class Ding
{
public:
    int value;
    Ding();
    ~Ding();
};
```

Ding.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Ding.h"
#include <iostream>

Ding::Ding()
{
    value = 90000;
    std::cout << "Constructor for ding called.";
}


Ding::~Ding()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor for ding called.";
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include "Ding.h"

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "starting." << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ding>> dingen;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         std::unique_ptr<Ding> toAdd(new Ding);
         dingen.push_back(std::move(toAdd));
    }
    std::cout << "ending" <<std::endl;

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I can see the memory errors in the debug output view:

> ```
> Detected memory leaks!
>
> Dumping objects -> {151} normal block at
>
> 0x00000155B0798140, 104 bytes long.  Data: <                > 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  {144} normal block at
> 0x00000155B07A2300, 16 bytes long.  Data: <  S             > 08 FB 53
> D3 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Object dump complete.
> ```

What creates these leaks?

edit: as dasblinkenlight answer stated I need to use (new Ding), I accicdently removed that part when trying to find the leak. Added it to the question as it does not solve the memory leak but calls the constructor and destrctor for ding.

Comment: You don't get any output from the constructor or destructor because you don't actually *create* any objects.

Comment: Well, for starters you never create any `Ding` objects. (What made you think you did?) But there are also no leaks in your code, so that is weird.

Comment: I wonder why it detects memory leaks though. Probably because everything is still on the stack? If you wrap everthing except for _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() in curly braces that issue might be solved.

Comment: @KerrekSB I changed my answer I accidently removed (new Ding) when looking for the leak. Adding new Ding dosnt solve the leak though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The leak is coming from std::vector. Putting in into a nested scope should fix the problem:

```
int main() {
    { // Open new scope
        std::cout << "starting." << std::endl;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ding>> dingen;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
             std::unique_ptr<Ding> toAdd;
             dingen.push_back(std::move(toAdd));
        }
        std::cout << "ending" <<std::endl;
    } // Close the scope

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The code doesn't create any `Ding` objects, which is why the constructor is never called. `std::unique_ptr<Ding> toAdd;` creates a `unique_ptr` object that holds a null pointer; it doesn't create a `Ding` object. To create one, use `operator new`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Ding> toAdd(new Ding);
```

Comment: Oops, I changed my code a bit to much when looking for the leak, what creates the leak though? I updated my question accordingly.